# We facing some issue after copy db into new table and upgrade command is not working showing these type of error

Tags: magento2

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'default-0-general/region/display_all' for key 'CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH', query was: INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

in reindex command => Catalog Search indexer process unknown error:
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/html/pashmina/suitings/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Config.php on line 341

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems after copy db like this.
mysqldump --host='localhost' --user='user' --password='password' --databases your_db --add-drop-table --debug-info --comments  --dump-date  --disable-keys --extended-insert --single-transaction --quick --verbose --result-file='dev_dump.sql'
Then on a different pc load it like this
mysql --host='localhost' --user='anotheruser' --password='anotherpassword' < dev_dump.sql